# How to programmatically set the state of a UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I use a UIGestureRecognizer:

```
panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Now, I want to be able to set the state of the GestureRecognizer to UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded so when I enter

```
- (void)foldToGallery:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
```

It will perform the code under:

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

and ignore the rest of the gesture until I will start a new one

Comment: Maybe you can set `gesture.enabled = NO`. That will lead to the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/enabled)). Maybe you can check on this state. And enable it again afterwards.

Comment: i posted this as an answer, so that this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can set `gesture.enabled = NO`
That will lead to the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/enabled)). Maybe you can check on this state and enable it again afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit more fragile than setting `enabled`, but KVC works, too:

```
[gesture setValue:@(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) forKey:@"state"];
```

This would be useful if you don't want your recognizer to transition to cancelled.